# Is the fibre-product functor $(-)\times_N M$ exact?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

Consider an abelian category $\mathcal C$; if it helps, modules over a sufficiently friendly ring. Let $N\in\mathcal C$. We can consider the over-category $\mathcal C_{/N}$ of objects from $\mathcal C$ with a fixed morphism to $N$. Let $M\in\mathcal C_{/N}$ (the morphism $M\to N$ is implicitly understood). We can form the functor
$$\begin{aligned}
(-)\times_N M\colon \mathcal C_{/N} &\to \mathcal C_{/N},\\
X &\mapsto X\times_N M.
\end{aligned}$$
Under which circumstances is this functor exact? I'd guess that in general it is only left exact (since I can write it as a kernel, and kernels are left exact), but I haven't worked out the details yet. Do you know an answer?

Comment: $\mathcal C_{/N}$ is not abelian if $N$ is nonzero-indeed it's not even pointed, since the identity of $N$ is terminal but the map $0\to N$ is initial.

Comment: Thats a good point. Would it make to ask the question in the following way: Given a s.e.s. $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ of objects in $\mathcal C$ which all have a morphism to $N$, under which circumstances is the sequence $0\to A\times_N M \to B\times_N M \to C\times_N M \to 0$ (partially) exact in $\mathcal C$?

Comment: Not really. The problem is that the maps from $A,B,C$ to $N$ would have to commute for the new sequence to be well defined, and then for instance the map from $A$ must be zero. If there’s a concrete situation around all this you’re interested in, I would go back to that and start the abstraction process again. For instance, a similarly sounding but more reasonable question could be: when, if ever, is the pullback functor $\mathcal C^{\bullet\to\bullet\leftarrow \bullet}\to \mathcal C$ exact? Here the domain is the category of diagrams $a\to b\leftarrow c$ in $\mathcal C$, which is abelian.